# Ruby State machine - subtract from symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I readed State Machine Ruby README.md at github.

I want to integrate SM with my Rails application.

However I am curious about what that line does:

```
before_transition :parked => any - :parked, :do => :put_on_seatbelt
```

Particulary this fragment looks like 'magic' to me:

```
any - :parked,
```

Soo, you subtract symbol from some kind of object(s) return by `any` helper.
How it is suppose to work and what exactly it does this entire line(`before_transition ...`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any` is a singleton instance of the `AllMathcher`, which represents *any state* of your model. The minus ("-") operator is actually an instance method of `AllMatcher` ([reference here](http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/StateMachine/AllMatcher#--instance_method)), which excludes the given state from the states of your model.

Therefore, if your model has states of `:running`, `:stopped`, and `:parked`, then `any - :parked` just returns states `:running` and `:stopped` (`:parked` is excluded).

And the meaning of the whole statement `before_transition :parked => any - :parked, :do => :put_on_seatbelt` is: before the model transits **from** `:parked` **to** any state but `:parked`, do the operation `:put_on_seatbelt`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the statemachine code (nor can I easily find it on github - a link might help); but I'd guess that `any` returns a set-like object containing symbols, which has `-` defined as element removal.

Given that, and applying a common-sense reading, I'd interpret the line as "Before moving from `:parked` state to any state other than `:parked`, you should do `:put_on_seatbelt`"